# How can I install FosJSRoutingBundle of Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I want't to install FosJSRoutingBundle, but the readme file say to install it by using `dep`.

Notice that I updated my app to **Symfony2.1** and I use `composer.json` and `composer.phar` to install any bundles (as suggested by the docs).

Hence, how can I install that bundle by using the **Composer** under Symfony2.1?

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1: Add [Packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) to your bookmarks.

Trust me, you'll be going there very often!

### Step 2: Find the package details and add to your `composer.json` file

To install a bundle in a Symfony 2.1.x application, you just need to search for it on Packagist and then add the name of the package, and the relevant version, to your `composer.json` file. So in this case, you'd find the [friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle) package. By looking at it's requirements, you'll see that the "dev-master" version (this is normally the version you'll want, but not always so be careful) caters for your current Symfony version: `symfony/framework-bundle: >=2.0,<2.2-dev`. So you just need to add the following into the `"require":` section of your `composer.json` file:

```
"friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Alternatively, composer.phar provides a way of doing this for you if you're happier on the command line:

```
$ php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle dev-master
```

### Step 3: Update your vendors

This just a case of running the following command. It will install the vendor and all of it's dependencies.

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

### NOTE

The difference between running `php composer.phar update` and `php composer.phar install` is that `update` will install the latest packages available based on your configuration and then write the current versions of each bundle into a `composer.lock` file. Using `install` instead will only install the versions that are currently listed in your `composer.lock` file.